# How to list recipes available under a chef environment

Tags: chef-infra, environment, knife

Is there a knife command I can issue that will list recipes available under a chef environment (based on the Cookbook Version Constraints)?

Adding additional information:

In the chef server interface, when you edit the node run list, I see when you select the environment from the drop down it makes a rest call:

/environments/development/recipes

Which returns an array of recipes. So there's no way to run a search query through knife to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

All recipes are always available per se, just a question of what versions things will resolve to. You can use the `knife-solve` gem to see version solutions fro your workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the notion here is that some recipes are not available in earlier versions of a cookbook.  Unfortunately, I'm now aware of any command that can list the recipes in a particular cookbook version, short of downloading the version and doing an `ls recipes` on it.  Likewise, there is not a knife command that can do this across all cookbooks/versions available to a given environment.

Comment: In the chef server interface, when you edit the node run list, I see when you select the environment it sends a rest request: https://chefserver/environments/development/recipes which returns an array of recipes. So there's no way to run a search query through knife?

Comment: There is a lot I don't know about chef, so I wouldn't say there is no way, but I'm not aware of one.  There may be a knife plugin, but I'm not aware of one.  That said, you are right that the API endpoint is there, so a knife plugin is very do-able.

Answer (score 0):

So there's no single command:

To get the available recipes for an environment using knife:

1. knife cookbook list -E development
2. Loop through result list from step
   a. knife cookbook show cookbook_name version